# Access php function data via ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have this php function inside a class the returns json data

```
function getPhotoDetails( $photoId ) {
   $url = $this::APP_URL . 'media/' . $photoId . $this::APP_ID;
   return $this->connectToApi($url);
}
```

and this ajax request

```
function getPhotoDetails( photoId ) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        url: 'index.php',
        success: function (data) {
               console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

The question is how I can call the php function to get the json data.

**Solution:**
A big thanks to all of you guys and thanks to Poonam

**The right code**

PHP: 
I created a new object instance in php file

```
$photoDetail = new MyClass;
if(isset($_REQUEST['image_id'])){
  $id = $_REQUEST['image_id'];
  echo (($photoDetail->getPhotoDetails($id)));
}
```

JavaScript

```
function getPhotoDetails( photoId ) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        url: './instagram.php?image_id=' + photoId,
        success: function (data) {
            var data = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(data);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: your php script is just like any normal script - an ajax connection is just another "kind" of browser.  You call the function just like you would on a regular PHP page - passing data with either POST or GET.

Then you would need to echo the return value of the php function, with json headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with setting some parameter to identify that details needs to send for e.g assuming photoid params needed for function

```
function getPhotoDetails( photoId ) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        url: 'index.php?sendPhoto=1&photoid=23',
        success: function (data) {
               console.log(data);
        }

    });
}
```

and then on `index.php` check (You can make check for photoid whatever you need as per requirement)

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['sendPhoto'])){
      $id = $_REQUEST['photoid'];
      return getPhotoDetails($id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

setup a switch-case. Pass the function name as GET or POST variable such that it calls the php function

Answer (score 0):

You need a file which calls the PHP function. You can't just call PHP functions from Ajax. And as pointed out by Tim G, it needs to use the proper header, format the code as JSON, and echo the return value (if the function is not already doing these things).